# How can I copy Excel sheets based on their name using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

The background:

- I have a directory containing multiple workbooks.
- Each workbook contains multiple sheets, both hidden and visible.
- I would like to copy one particular sheet from each workbook into an existing master workbook.

The problem:

- At the moment, my code copies the first sheet in each source workbook.
- I require the code to copy only the sheet called "[current month] Summary", which is most often not the first sheet in the source workbooks.
- Because the [current month] will change, it needs to copy the sheet where the last seven letters of the name are "Summary".

My code as it stands:

```
Dim wbDst As Workbook
Dim wbSrc As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Dim MyPath As String
Dim strFilename As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
MyPath = InputBox("Please copy and paste the path to the folder containing the source documents")
Set wbDst = ActiveWorkbook
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xls", vbNormal)

If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

Do Until strFilename = ""

        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & "\" & strFilename)

        Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)

        wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)

        wbSrc.Close False

    strFilename = Dir()

Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets(1)
```

With

```
Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Worksheets("[current month] Summary")
```

**Edit:**

Replace your current Do Until Code with the below one :)

```
Do Until strFilename = ""
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & "\" & strFilename)

    For Each ws In wbSrc.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "summary", vbTextCompare) Then
            Set wsSrc = ws
        End If
    Next ws

    wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)
    wbSrc.Close False
    strFilename = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: This won't work when the month changes. Are you able to explain how to only copy sheets where the last 7 characters of its name are "summary"? Thank you!

Comment: I get the following error message at the line beginning "For Each...": Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Oops.. it's my mistake since I missed wbSrc.Worksheets and written wbSrc earlier.  Please take the revised one which is updated above.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will get the current month and after checking the name in workbooks will give you the desired result:

```
Dim currMonth As String
currMonth = MonthName(Month(Now))

Do Until strFilename = ""
        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyPath & "\" & strFilename)
        For Each ws In wbSrc.Worksheets
            If ws.Name = currMonth & "Summary" Then
                Debug.Print ws.Name
                Set wsSrc = ws
                wsSrc.Copy After:=wbDst.Worksheets(wbDst.Worksheets.Count)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        wbSrc.Close False
    strFilename = Dir()
Loop
```